# Is there any way to decode/encode by tag but without any .proto file or json file in protobuf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, protobufjs

Is there any way to decode/encode by tag but without any .proto file or json file in protobuf.js?
Or any other library?

like:

```js
// read value by tag
var pb = new Protobufjs.Reader(buffer);
var value = pb.readInt32ByTag(1);
```

```js
// write value by tag
var pb = new Protobufjs.Writer();
pb.writeInt32ByTag(1, 12345);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out https://github.com/pawitp/protobuf-decoder, it's also has a online decoder: https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.com/